# undefined reference to symbol 'vtkImageAlgorithm::GetOutput()'

Tags: linux, linker, cmake, makefile, vtk

I want to build a project using `make` in Ubuntu. This project includes VTK, Xerces and Cmake libraries. While builing I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX static library libMA_LaTIM.a
     [ 96%] Built target MA_LaTIM
     Scanning dependencies of target MA_LaTIM_entrainement
     [100%] Building CXX object applications/CMakeFiles/MA_LaTIM_entrainement.dir/entrainement.cxx.o
Linking CXX executable MA_LaTIM_entrainement
    /usr/bin/ld: ../algorithmes/libMA_LaTIM.a(LecteurImage.cxx.o): undefined     reference to symbol 'vtkImageAlgorithm::GetOutput()'    
    /usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtkImageAlgorithm::GetOutput()' is defined in DSO     /usr/lib/libvtkFiltering.so.5.8 so try adding it to the linker command line
    /usr/lib/libvtkFiltering.so.5.8: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this problem? Here is my [CMakeLists.txt](http://pastebin.com/JfGCrjjk), and here is my [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/BtZphzvq).

Comment: Thanks a lot. aymericbeaumet

Comment: Does you CmakeLists.txt have something like target_link_libraries(SimplePointsReader ${VTK_LIBRARIES}) ? Are you sure the installation of VTK was correct (are you able to run examples)?

Comment: use VERBOSE=yes to get the compiler line and check that you link against the vtk libraries

Comment: I have the same problem, but I do not use cmake. Which Library contains this definition?

Comment: I found out how to find the VTK library to link to resolve the linker error `undefined     reference to symbol`!
the problem is, that e.g. with my version VTK 6.1 there are 377 shared libs to choose from. Well, some are as before with version 5 but split in Core and special libs. Others can be found if you check the header of the module the compiler complains about: there is a macro between "class" and the class name: "class VTK_......_EXPORT" <classname>, which gives you a hint how the lib is named. 
E.g. `class VTKRENDERINGCORE_EXPORT vtkRenderer` needs library libvtkRenderingCore.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to not use cmake to build your application, here is the solution  to resolve the linker error `undefined reference to symbol` with VTK!
The libraries have to be chosen manually. The problem is, that e.g. with my version VTK 6.1 there are 377 shared libs to choose from. Well, some are as before with version 5 but split in Core and special libs.

Others can be found if you check the header of the module the compiler complains about: there is a macro between "class" and the class name: "class VTK_......_EXPORT" , which gives you a hint how the lib is named.
E.g. `class VTKRENDERINGCORE_EXPORT vtkRenderer` needs library libvtkRenderingCore. Here an example (Linux) which worked for my application:

```
-L/usr/lib64/vtk -lvtkCommonCore -lvtkFiltersCore -lvtkRenderingCore  -lvtkImagingCore -lvtkCommonExecutionModel -l vtkCommonDataModel \
            -lvtkFiltersSources -lvtkFiltersGeometry -lvtkFiltersGeneral -lvtkIOCore -lvtkIOImage -lvtkRenderingOpenGL
```